# Flask application running on nginx . File read from folder ok but 500 error while file save

Tags: ubuntu, python, nginx

Hello I am running nginx server on ubuntu system .
file read from web app is OK .
file save or file write to local folder system is getting error with 500 internal server error .

```
root       12145  0.0  0.2  55208  2236 ?        Ss   23:33   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
root       12146  0.0  0.6  55860  6204 ?        S    23:33   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

I have provided read/write access to filesystem folder but this doesn't work .

When I run my application with python command i.e. `python app.py`

Both file read and write works fine .

I am not sure where I am going wrong .